# Controlled by parent for lookups

Tags: case, permissions, sharing

Say I want to have Cases to be shared with parent account owners.

By default, cases have a lookup relationship into Account and cannot be changed into master detail.

What is the most elegant solution to this?

So far I can only imagine Apex sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do it via Role hierarchy. If all account owners fall in same role, you can edit their role to provide following permission "Users in this role can **view all/edit All** cases associated with accounts that they own, regardless of who owns the cases"

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that will do for Cases. How about custom objects?